# Httpweb request with datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

So i have httpget request, that should return a `datatable` from my database. I convert my datatable into `EnumerableRowCollection` ,then serialize it into json string (using json.net):

```
public string GetResult(DataTable dt)
{
 EnumerableRowCollection Result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     account = (string)row["ACCOUNT_ID"],
                                     balance = (decimal)row["BALANCE"]
                                 }; 
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Result, Formatting.None);
 return json;
}
```

And then i pass it to the controller.

It's ok - except one thing - controller itself is serializing the request and i get a double serialized json string with back slashes (here is a part of a json):

```
[{\"account\":\"121\",\"balance\":-348}]
```

I can't figure out how else can i pass the `EnumerableRowCollection`  (not using a json string), so that i wont get a double serialized json? (or maybe i shouldnt convert it to a `EnumerableRowCollection` at all?)

Answer (score 0):

All a WebAPI can return is the serialized representation of the object you want to return.

In this code, you're serializing an object into a JSON string, and then that string is encoded again to become a JSON string. This causes the double quoting.

You don't need to serialize the object yourself, and there's no use for using an `EnumerableRowCollection` indeed. Create a DTO:

```
public class AccountBalanceModel
{
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }    
}
```

Then return that from your API method, and let WebAPI deal with the serialization:

```
public IList<AccountBalanceModel> GetResult(DataTable dt)
{
    var model = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new AccountBalanceModel
                {
                    Account = (string)row["ACCOUNT_ID"],
                    Balance = (decimal)row["BALANCE"]
                }).ToList(); 

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Ty ! Worked for me. Except .ToList(), it only worked if i call return model.ToList()

Comment: Yeah that was a small syntax error, I generally use fluent syntax.